# Adjusting UIbutton Image

Tags: objective-c

My UIbutton was stretching my images I was assigning to it with

```
[self.BTN_pic_1 setImage:myPIC forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

I used this code to the correct resizing mode like this

```
 [self.BTN_pic_1 setContentMode:UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit];
```

The aspect fit only works once I press the button. I want the Aspect Fit to start working as soon as I load the image.

How can I get the button to do that?

Comment: Interesting. I haven't tried this, but have you tried telling the button that it needs redrawing?

Comment: Also note that in your code you are talking to two different buttons. Your problem could be as simple as that.

Comment: I don't see anything in apple docs about redrawing and I don't want to call the action into play without user interaction.

Comment: The example has been fixed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not the button's content mode you want to fix; it's the content mode of the button's `imageView`. That is what is holding the image you assign when you call `setImage:forState:`.

Comment: Thank you, the answer was [self.BTN_pic_main.imageView setHighlighted:YES];

Answer (score 1):

Use the imageEdgeInsets to control how the image is stretched.

or

Set the contentMode of the button's imageView instead of the button's.
     [self.BTN_pic_1.imageView setContentMode:UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit];

**Disclaimer:**
There are many posible answers to this, you'll probably need to be more specific before we can give you a definitive answer.

Comment: too late, matt wins ;)